# RoR undefined method `persisted?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

i am trying to make a form in RoR using carrierwave and i am getting the following error:

```
**undefined method `persisted?' for Code(Table doesn't exist):Class**
```

Here is the code from my form:

```
    = form_for Code, :as => :code, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|

        p
           = f.file_field :code
        p
           = f.submit
```

And the problematic line is:

```
   = f.submit
```

Here is my model:

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :name, :code
    mount_uploader :code, CodeUploader

end
```

Also i will be glad if someone could tell me why is (Table doesn't exist) appearing.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks to both readers and answerers. {:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run db migrations with:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This will fix the "Table doesn't exist" message.

Then, replace `Code` from your form with `Code.new` and it should work:

```
= form_for Code.new, :as => :code, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
```

I'd also advice you to learn some basics about Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an instance of the class to the `form_for` method

```
= form_for Code.new, :as => :code, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
```